# Apache can't interpret a link in my webpage so the style is not good, what I can do?

Tags: html, apache, browser

Apache can't interpret the following link :
`<link href="../../chorus-theme/css/main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

because of @browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623 after main.css

but when I open the html file directly in the browser it works, the style is applied. if I use the url link:

`http://localhost:8080/TCS/group/guest`

the style is not anymore applied, it can't read main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623.
If I rename main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623 to main.css and change it also in the html file, the style is applied.

Could anyone help? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by it "works" or "doesn't work"?

Comment: Apache doesn't interpret a link, the browser is the one who resolves it to an absolute path!

Comment: I mean that the style is not applied

Comment: So Matthias why it resolves it well, when I open it in the directory and not via a url link (apache used behind) ?

Comment: Does the file `main.css@browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623` exist? Including the @ and = and & characters. Otherwise, apache probably isn't going to give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problems, need to put
text/css css?browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623 in the mime.type file

another solution is to rename
main.css?browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623 in
main.css?browserId=firefox&t=1344590189623.css